# Get Variable Values in View.xml

Tags: magento2, product-view

I am trying to create a custom module with a block that should get the values of variables in view.xml. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer here. It provides all the needed steps you do to get the variable values in view.xml
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html#view_xml_vars

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding please have a look this view

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/view.xml

with the following implementation

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.0/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Image/ParamsBuilder.php#L173

Answer (score 0):

You can get the variables from etc/view.xml files in a couple of ways.

Let's assume we want to get the value of product_image_size from the Magento_Wishlist module... https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/etc/view.xml

### In a Template (.phtml) File

```php
<?= $block->getVar('product_image_size', 'Magento_Wishlist') ?>
```

*Remember to [properly escape this output](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/cross-site-scripting/) depending on how you are using it (not shown)*

### In a PHP Class

```php
$this->viewConfig->getViewConfig()
    ->getVarValue('Magento_Wishlist', 'product_image_size');
```

Here is an example within a full custom block...

```php
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class YourBlock extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    protected $viewConfig;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConfigInterface $viewConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $viewConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->viewConfig = $viewConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get product_image_size
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductImageSize(): int
    {
        return (int) $this->viewConfig->getViewConfig()
            ->getVarValue('Magento_Wishlist', 'product_image_size');
    }
}
```